# Github Actions to Bump Version and create a Release

Tags: github-actions

Trying to make a CI pipeline that will bump root package.json and tag repo using a machine user access token, then have another workflow that triggers to make releases.

But currently, the release workflow never seems to fire.

Linke to a example repo https://github.com/labithiotis/ci-tag-release

I've noticed my PAT in github says it's never been used.

version.yml

```
  name: Versioning
  
  on:
    workflow_run:
      workflows: [CI]
      branches: [main]
      types:
        - completed
  
  jobs:
    versioning:
      if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
      name: Increment Versions
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Increment API version
          uses: phips28/gh-action-bump-version@master
          env:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.HAL_PAT }}
          with:
            tag-prefix: v
```

release.yml

```
name: Release

on:
  push:
    tags: ['v*']

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release Builds
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn wsrun -p @kernel/plugin.main -m build
      - name: Release Builds
        uses: marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest
        with:
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          prerelease: false
          files: *
```

Comment: Please try and create a minimal reproducible example. For your specific case, you might want to demonstrate/verify how/whether this works when pushing a tag manually.

Comment: @rethab I have added link to example repo, manual pushes work, it just seems like the previous action to bump version that use a PAT doesn't trigger release action

Comment: Do you have access to that PAT such that you could reproduce that outside of actions? Also note that the in general, commits (not sure about tags) created by the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` don't trigger actions, because that could lead to loops.

Comment: @rethab Yer was aware that GITHUB actions bot couldn't trigger other actions, it's why I have my own token in there for making tags. I logged out the details of tokens inside the custom tag action and confirm it was used in URL but github still say its unused, its very odd. I just fell like the commit inside tagging action is using GITHUB_TOKEN even though I set a different one.